# How to safely handle a async range that the user change between checks?

Tags: swift

I've run into an out of range error when the user rapidly swipes through a collection view. I set a variable,

```
var gloablIndex : Int
```

that keeps track of the index of the page currently displayed to the user. This value is changed in the UIScrollView method:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) 
{
     globalIndex = currentIndex
}
```

In another function, I check to see if the current page index - 1 will be within the range of my data array like so:

```
func changeLabel(velocity: CGPoint) 
{
    if velocity.x.isLess(than: CGFloat(0)) { 
        if ((0...dataSource.count).contains(globalIndex - 1)) { //Check One 
            if dataSource[globalIndex - 1].foo ?? false { //CheckTwo
                //do something
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

This function is called in the UIScrollView method:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) { changeLabel() }
```

When a user quickly swipes left repeatedly on the first page (`globalIndex = 0`), it can cause a `Fatal error: Index out of range: file` at the line containing `//check two`. I believe this is due to the value of `globalIndex` changing in between `//check one` and `//check two`.

I would be okay with the above operation failing safely, but I cannot think of a way to guard the value of `globalIndex` between both checks. Any help or workarounds are appreciated. I've tried a few different things, but the asynchronous nature of swift is new to me.

Comment: What function calls `changeLabel`? If it is on a background thread, you can wrap it in `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: @Daniel it is called in scrollViewWillEndDragging()

Comment: “the asynchronous nature of swift is new to me” Swift doesn’t have an asynchronous nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having problems with the value changing, then lock it into place.

```
func changeLabel(velocity: CGPoint) {
    let index = globalIndex - 1
    let data = dataSource

    if velocity.x.isLess(than: 0.0) {
        if data.indices.contains(index) { //Check One
            if data[index].foo ?? false { //CheckTwo
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A better idea is pass the properties into `changeLabel` as parameters.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    changeLabel(velocity: velocity, data: dataSource, index: globalIndex - 1)
}

func changeLabel(velocity: CGPoint, data: [MyData], index: Int) {
        if velocity.x.isLess(than: 0.0) {
        if data.indices.contains(index) { //Check One
            if data[index].foo ?? false { //CheckTwo
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```